# SQL Index Optimization For Join + Group By + Order By + Select On Example Code

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have a sql like below;

```
Select  m.org_id, r.country_or_region, 
sum(r.impressions), sum(r.taps) from 
metadata_table m
left join report_table r on r.org_id = m.org_id
where (r.report_date between '2019-05-30' and '2019-09-08') 
and r.org_id in (1433750, 135710, 1207280, 479360, 26320) 
group by r.country_or_region
order by sum(r.impressions) DESC
limit 0,20
```

And Here is my indexes;
For report_table;

```
index1(org_id, report_date);
index2(country_or_region, text);
```

For metadata_table;

```
index(org_id)
```

My problem in here, This sql takes more than 30 seconds for more than 1 million rows and I want to fetch it effectively. Because to sum all impressions ..., it should traverse whole rows. Also it is same for ordering.

MySQL Explain shows like that for above sql query;

```
table  type     possible_keys      key         extra
'r',   'ALL',   'index1, index2'   ,NULL,  'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'm', 'ref',     'index',          'index',  'Using where'
```

Comment: For report_table how many rows, how many unique org_id, how many unique report_date. What indexes are on metadata_table, how many rows, how many unique org_id?

Comment: First make sure you use GROUP BY correctly before optimizing..

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal, report_table(rows; 100 million, orgId: 1000, report_date: 750). metadata_table(rows; 100k, org_id: 1000, index: org_id)

Comment: @Sha You have to correct the group by. If m.valid has MANY unique values than you can change the index on metadata_table to index(org_Id, valid).

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal, In here, my problem is not group by (I've just simplified it.) My problem in here, to scan all table for ordering on aggregate data.

Comment: @Sha I understand the issue. Based upon the information you have provided the index definitions are correct.

Comment: You have a bug in your SQL. The predicate `and m.valid = 1` defeats the outer join, effectively converting it to an inner join. Maybe you wanted something like `and (m.valid = 1 or m.valid is null)`?

Comment: ...and your `GROUP BY` is incorrect as @RaymondNijland says.

Comment: The only reason for looking at `metadata_table` is to check `valid`.  Remove that, or move the flag to the other table, and it can run a lot faster.  Furthermore, that is a `JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Consider a [_summary table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: @Sha please edit the question and add the complete result of `Explain..` which also shows the count of rows being accessed, filtered etc, from both the tables.